# How to initialize SDL in a library that may be used by a program already depending on SDL?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, sdl

I want to use SDL_net for a helper library that will be used by a small number of programs. However, some of these programs might already be using SDL themselves. If I unterstand things right, this means I can't blindly use `SDL_Init` and `SDL_Quit` when initializing/freeing my library, because the SDL instance is shared between the main program and my library.

My best idea so far is to let the program pass a parameter indicating whether it is already using SDL, which would make the program responsible for calling SDL_Init first. I wonder though whether there is a cleaner solution. `SDL_WasInit` looked promising, but apparently only allows to check for initialized subsystems, not whether SDL itself is initialized (which might be done with `SDL_Init(0)`).

This is about SDL 1.2.

Comment: SDL 1.2, but if the answer is different for 1.3 and later it would be interesting to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

`SDL_WasInit()` can be used to to check if specific subsystems are running, through a check like `SDL_WasInit(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0` but the [SDL docs](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_WasInit) on SDL_WasInit() also say that if you pass in `SDL_WasInit(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0` or `SDL_WasInit(0) != 0`, this will let you know if any of the subsystems of SDL are running.

Comment: As I said in my question, I already tried `SDL_WasInit`. After calling `SDL_init(0)`, both `SDL_WasInit(0)` and `SDL_WasInit(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)` still return 0.